# How to install MS VisualStudio 2015 community edition in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install MS Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition) on Ubuntu 14.10 machine I have tried wine but it didn't worked as expected.

Comment: As it uses .NET I doubt that it will work anytime soon. Even if it worked, I wouldn't advise using it. You are better off using alternative software. If you really need it, consider virtualization.

Comment: This is a little bit of a sidetracked response, but have you given Mono/Xamarin a whirl? If you are developing for *nix this might be a more fitting solution. Granted, some of the more complex libraries flaky (like `System.Reflection`) or just not there (like ASP.Net and WPF). Check out [compatability](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/) if you are interested.

Comment: Did you even check https://www.winehq.org/announce/1.7.31?

Comment: @Braiam: What about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have tried wine but it didn't worked as expected

Yeah, VS will require a full and proper Windows stack. Wine simply won't cut it.

You'll need to either dual-boot or use virtualisation (Virtualbox, VMWare, etc) to install a proper copy of Windows. I'd probably go with a virtual machine but it'll likely be somewhat slower than a native install - which may be an issue if you're compiling lots. The up-side is you'll never have to leave Ubuntu.

Other than that, you probably want to look at transitioning your projects away from .NET and into Mono. It'll be a while until the recent open source .NET stuff hits a usable state, and even then, it'll probably only be a target. I doubt MS will port VS to be cross platform.

Comment: One annoying thing on using VMs to work is that you can't `<alt> + <tab>` between windows. On your VM, you can use PuTTY and forward X11 to xming. It will render the Ubunto windows directly into the VM. You need SSH running for this. Also, you can get free and legal VMs on http://modern.ie/